# Test in Ember.js does never end, it just keeps running

Tags: testing, ember.js, ember-cli, ember-qunit

I am currently learning how to test Ember apps and I have an issue I cannot resolve for myself.

The problem is that when the test I wrote runs, it never ends. It just keeps running, like it has a promise that never resolves or something? This is the test:

```
test("User signs in and is redirected to his dashboard", function() {
    visit('/');
    fillIn('input#identification', 'test');
    fillIn('input#password', 'test');
    click('input#login');

    andThen(function() {
        ok(currentRouteName() === 'dashboard', 'redirected to dashboard');
    });
});
```

The `andThen` function is never triggered, it seems like the promise of click never resolves. I made the routes and templates etc. so minimalistic as possible to avoid other interfering code.

Also I am using `ember-simple-auth`, maybe that this could explain any behaviour?

This is a screenshot of the problem:
[image]

Comment: Does it login and redirect?

Comment: @Kingpin2k Yes it does, I think I already fixed it by updating to latest ember-simple-auth.

Comment: Good to hear, will you update your question with your previous version, and add an answer with the updated version?  Thanks